# Sorting of table in android when clicked on any column's header

Tags: android, listview

There is a table with two columns. One column is Name, second is  Age. 
Now I want to design it in such a way that when I click on column header then it should sort the table as per the column. For example, if I click on 'Name' column then should be sorted as per the names. If I click on 'Age' then table should be sorted as per age.
I am also confused that for designing this table should I use listview or table.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done by a ListView with ArrayAdapter. The ArrayAdapter stores your data and has two public functions to sort the data by one or the other field. These functions are called by the buttons and then you just invalidate (`notifyDataSetChanged()`) your listview (which has the ArrayAdapter as Datasource).

Comment: of what? An ArrayAdapter is the standard way to deliver data to a ListView. There are tons of tutorials about that. Each ArrayAdapter has an ArrayList to keep the data. This data can be sorted. If you do not know how to do one of these three things, you should search for that but not ask me to write your code.